# snap and apt usage to install the tor browser bundle?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, security, linux, ubuntu, tor-install

Not to put too fine a point on it, but neither `snap` nor `apt` are [suitable](https://askubuntu.com/q/1161618/45156) for installing current versions of the `tor` browser?

I see the downloads are available [directly](https://www.torproject.org/download/) from the `tor` site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a statement and didn't ask a question, but anyway...

There is a third party tool called [torbrowser-Launcher](https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher) that is incorporated into many Linux distributions. This will automatically download the latest version of Tor Browser direction from the Tor website, it will check GPG keys to make sure they are correct, and it will even make icons for your in your manu. If you don't trust it, then the best way is to download the tarball from the Tor website yourself, manually check the key that it is signed with, etc. I see no reason not to use torbrowser-Launcher (I trust it more than the Android Play store) but each person needs to be aware of their own security needs.